# javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class

Tags: servlets, jboss7.x

Am trying to access the url from JBOss server.. i have an error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.tg.simReplacementApi.ReplaceSim
            org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
            org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
            org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
            org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
            org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
            org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
            java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
        root cause

        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tg.simReplacementApi.ReplaceSim from [Module "deployment.ReplacementSim.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
            org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
            org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
            org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
            org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
            org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
            org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72)
            org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
            org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
            org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
            org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
            org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
            org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
            java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

and my web.xml

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
     "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
     "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

    <web-app>
      <display-name>Web Application</display-name>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ReplaceSim</servlet-name>
        <display-name>ReplaceSim</display-name>
        <description></description>
        <servlet-class>com.tg.simReplacementApi.ReplaceSim</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ReplaceSim</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ReplaceSim</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

and servlet is ReplaceSim.java

```
package com.tg.simReplacementApi;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ReplaceSim
 */
public class ReplaceSim extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public ReplaceSim(){

    }

  /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        Member member = new Member();
        member.setPhoneNo(request.getParameter("phone"));
        member.setSimSerial(request.getParameter("simSerial"));
        WebServiceCaller call = new WebServiceCaller();
        String resp = call.getReplacementSim(member);
        System.out.println(resp);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

}
```

and successfully deployed into jboss7.1.1 server. When accessing the url this error is occurring. in localhost the application is working fine.

can anybody know why it causing error.. thanks in advance

Comment: You need to double check the class is in the WAR and where it's at in the WAR. It should be in `WAR/WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: when i deploying in tomcat working properly and testing with jboss7.1 in localhost it working properly. it occurs only i deploying in server. am i missing any configurations in server?.

Comment: If it's only on a server it sounds like an environmental issue. You may want to make sure you're deploying to the same server version and deploying the same WAR.